# Regex Wild Card question

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, wildcard

**Code:**

```
strx = "exam/unwanted_tex/ple";
strx = strx.replace(/\/.+\//, '');
alert(strx); // Alerts "example"
```

**2 quick questions:**

1. This code replaces everything within "/" and "/"?
2. What difference is to use ".*" instead of ".+"

Comment: Mozilla Dev Network is one of your most valuable resources for general JS reference. Use it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. `'*'` and `'+'` are called quantifiers.  `'*'` matches the character or group that precedes it zero or more times. In a sense, this makes the match optional.  `'+'` matches the character or group that precedes one or more times.  In your particular example there is no practical difference. However, when used in other applications the distinction is very important.  Here is an example:

`'*'` Quantifier (match zero or more times)

```
// Match 'y' in Joey zero or more times
strx = "My name is Joe";
strx = strx.replace(/Joey*/, 'Jack');
alert(strx)  // Alerts "My Name is Jack"
```

`'+'` Quantifier (match one or more times)

```
// Match 'y' in Joey one or more times
strx = "My name is Joe";
strx = strx.replace(/Joey+/, 'Jack');
alert(strx)  // Alerts "My Name is Joe"
```

Comment: just because you gave a clear example, i will chose your answer over 'Jared Ng'

Comment: Thanks! Regex is really cool stuff. If you're interested in digging deeper check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/..  Even basic regex knowledge opens up a lot of possibilities that are difficult or impossible to achieve otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that is correct
2. `.*` means: `.` match any single character, `*` zero or more times,

   `.+` means: `.` match any single character, `+` one or more times

Answer (score 0):

1. yes
2. ".*" = any character ANY number of time. ".+" = any character ONE OR MORE times